# Using C# and .NET 4, how to solve issue where Assembly.GetTypes() throws a ReflectionTypeLoadException?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a plugin for a third party application. I can't make any changes to that third party application.

The third party application implements a plugin system that basically scans a directory for DLLs that implement a particular interface. Unfortunately, they have a rather fatal flaw - as they scan the DLLs, they call `assembly.getTypes()` on each assembly, which can throw a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, which they completely swallow - I've used .NET Reflector plugin in the IDE to see that they have an empty catch block.

The problem I am seeing is that my plugin is causing such an exception, but I don't understand how the CLR loads things so I am unsure how to resolve the issue.

When the exception is thrown, the message is `Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.`
When I look at the `LoaderExceptions`, there is a single item in the list:

`Could not load file or assembly 'StevesStuff.CommonBridges, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The assembly referenced in that message is a dependency for the main plugin assembly, and it is in the same directory as the main plugin.

This is all in .NET 4.0, which I am unable to change as it is the framework that the third party program is using.

Comment: File a bug with the owner, tell them they need to use LoadFrom() instead.  Meanwhile, deploy the dependency in the GAC or the directory that contains the .exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of investigation, I created a test harness that I hoped was a good stand-in for the third party application's plugin loading code. As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) mentioned in his comment to my question, I used the `Assembly.LoadFile()` method in my test harness and found that it failed in about the same way as the real third party plugin loading code. I then changed my test harness to use `LoadFrom()` instead, and the test harness was able to load the plugin successfully.

We are now using a multi-prong approach to the problem. Because we want the plugin to work with an existing version of the third party software, we are going to change the build process for the plugin to compile in the source of the dependency, so that the plugin is a single assembly rather than a main assembly and a dependent assembly. Now that I understand the nature of the failure, I feel like this will likely solve the issue.

At the same time, we are filing a bug report with the third party, in case they do want to address the issue, and we are also getting a copy of the latest version of the third party software to test against in the off chance that they have found and fixed the issue already.